# CSS select first button with same class of the second button

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

It's as simple as it looks like. I want to `display:none;` the first `button`. I have two of them with same parent class. For some reason I can't figure out why I don't achieve the result I want.

```css
.main-content .cbToolBar:first-child button{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <span class="cbToolBar">
    <button class="cbButton"></button>
  </span>
  <span class="cbToolBar">
    <button class="cbButton"></button>
  </span>
</div>
```

There is something wrong with my selection but I can't figure out what.

Thanks.

Comment: You selector looks correct to match the first button in your example markup. Check if there are some other tags before the first `.cbToolBar` in the production markup

Comment: browser issue maybe, what are you using?

Comment: @feeela Yes there are other tags before but at the same level as 'cbToolBar' span, but I thought it would select the first child called 'cbToolBar'.

Comment: When facing a problem with something that doesn't work the way you're expecting it to, you should avoid composing your question with any assumptions about what you think it should do. Otherwise you potentially end up with an unanswerable question because the critical information is missing. In this case, that critical information refers to the additional elements in your markup.

Comment: No, `:first-child` does exactly what is says it does – selecting the first child element of a parent container. You really should post the markup in qestion to get useful answers…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...there are other tags before but at the same level as 'cbToolBar' span, but I thought it would select the first child called 'cbToolBar'.

CSS's `:first-child` pseudo-class selector selects specifically *the* first child, regardless of it's class. The [documentation on `:first-child` states](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo):

> Same as `:nth-child(1)`. The :first-child pseudo-class represents an element that is the first child of some other element.

There are several workarounds. The one I'd suggest is that if your `.cbToolBar` elements are the only `span` elements within your `.main-content` parent, you can instead use the [`:first-of-type` pseudo-class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo):

> Same as `:nth-of-type(1)`. The `:first-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.

```css
.main-content .cbToolBar:first-of-type button{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <p>Hello, world!</p>
  <span class="cbToolBar">
    <button class="cbButton">Button 1</button>
  </span>
  <span class="cbToolBar">
    <button class="cbButton">Button 2</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Or, if you know the exact position of your element you want to hide, you can always just use `:nth-child(n)`. In this example, the element we want to hide is the second one, so we use `:nth-child(2)`:

```css
.main-content .cbToolBar:nth-child(2) button{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <p>Hello, world!</p>
  <span class="cbToolBar">
    <button class="cbButton">Button 1</button>
  </span>
  <span class="cbToolBar">
    <button class="cbButton">Button 2</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: So how would I select the first element called `.cbToolBar` inside `.main-content`?

Comment: Thank you, it works. `first-of-type` Ohhh there is something I've never used/heard of. I even searched for selectors but didn't find this.

Comment: @azhpo here's the official list of CSS Level 3 selectors: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at it before but I scrolled so fast didnt even see it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the general sibling combinator in this case.

- Set a rule for all elements with a certain class
- Use the combinator to select following siblings and unset the rule

```css
.cbToolBar button {
  display: none;
}
.cbToolBar ~ .cbToolBar button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <span>span</span>
  <span class="cbToolBar">
    <button class="cbButton">button</button>
  </span>
  <span>span</span>
  <span class="cbToolBar">
    <button class="cbButton">button</button>
  </span>
  <span>span</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works too. Although I used the previous answer's solution. Thank you anyways.